# Failed to read when no data is present

Tags: vb.net, sqldatareader

i have this code,,its work (kind of).

```
Dim connString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connectionstring").ConnectionString
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connString)
    conn.Open()
    Dim comm As New SqlCommand("SELECT username, Password,type   FROM users WHERE username='" & TextBox1.Text & "' AND Password='" & TextBox2.Text & "'", conn)
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader
    reader = comm.ExecuteReader

    Dim count As Integer
    count = 0
    While reader.Read
        count = count + 1
    End While
    If count = 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("username and password are correct")


        Form2.Show()


        Form2.Label1.Text = Me.TextBox1.Text
        Form2.Label2.Text = reader(2).ToString
    ElseIf count > 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("username and password are duplicated")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("username and password are wrong")

    End If
```

im getting error with this line:

```
Form2.Label2.Text = reader(2).ToString
and error is "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present"
```

why its says "no data"

i have all data in database?

can someone help me to correct this code?
thank you ..

Comment: Your While loop will continue until reader.Read returns False meaning there is no more data. You have reached the end of the data and cannot access reader(2). If you want to get the type, do it immediately after the first reader.Read.

Comment: You should not concatenate strings in your SQL query. Use parameters to prevent SQL injection. Also, you should never store passwords as plain text.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using a loop at all.  There should be no way that you can get more than one record so what use would a loop be?  You should be using an `If` statement and that's all:

```
If reader.Read() Then
    'There was a match and you can get the data from reader here.
Else
    'There was no match.
End If
```

If it's possible to have two records with the same username then there's something wrong with your database design and your app.  That column should be unique and your app should be testing for an existing record when someone tries to register.

Answer (score 0):

A SqlDataReader is a forward only data read element. The error is occurring because you're calling the reader's READ function twice; once as true to increment to 1, and a second time to get a false to fall out of the while statement. Since you're no longer in the WHILE statement, the reader had to have read the end of the result set, thus there is no data for you to read.

Consider the changed code below:

```
Dim connString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connectionstring").ConnectionString
Dim count As Integer = 0 
Dim userType as string = ""

Using conn As New SqlConnection(connString)
    conn.Open()
    Using Comm as SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand 
       comm.commandText = "SELECT username, Password, type FROM Users WHERE username = @UserName AND Password = @Pwd; "
       comm.parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", TextBox1.Text) 
       comm.parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Textbox2.text) 

       Dim reader As SqlDataReader
       reader = comm.ExecuteReader

       If reader IsNot Nothing Then 
          If reader.HasRows() Then 
             While reader.read 
                count = count + 1 
                If Not reader.IsDbNull(2) Then userType = reader(2).ToString 
             End While 
          End If 
          If Not reader.IsClosed Then reader.close
          reader = Nothing 
       End If 
    End Using 
End Using
If count = 1 Then
    MessageBox.Show("username and password are correct")
    Form2.Show()

    Form2.Label1.Text = Me.TextBox1.Text
    Form2.Label2.Text = userType 
 ElseIf count > 1 Then
    MessageBox.Show("username and password are duplicated")
 Else
    MessageBox.Show("username and password are wrong")
 End If
```

First off, SQLParameters are your friend. Learn them. They are the single easiest way to fight against SQL Injection when using the SqlClient classes.

Secondly, notice that I'm doing the actual retrieval of the data from the reader inside the WHILE loop. This ensures that there's actual data for me to read.

Third, notice the USING statements on the SqlConnection and SqlCommand objects. This helps with garbage collection, and has a couple of other benefits as well.

Finally, notice the checks I'm doing on the SqlDataReader before I ever attempt to access it. Things like that would prevent from another error appearing if you did not return any results.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i just want to ask.what is cn.CreateCommand ? cos im getting error there

Comment: Sorry, I always use cn for my connection objects, and typed that instead of Conn

Comment: `AddWithValue`, dont use it, use `Add` and specify the datatype along with length. When not doing so, it is infering the type and may not be what you want... Also theres a few reserved keywords in that select statement, they should be enclosed in brakets `[ ]` just MHO...

Comment: @StephenWrighton `If reader IsNot Nothing Then ` is not necessary. `reader = comm.ExecuteReader` returns a reader whether or not there are rows. If there is a problem with the command it will blow up before it reaches the If statement.

Comment: @StephenWrighton ` If reader.HasRows() Then ` is not necessary. `While reader.read ` will return False immediately if there are no rows,